# What does this "return ~Result(0)" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have never seen this before... just curious to know what "return ~Result(0)" does.

```
Simple::Result Screen::pickPoint(const Point& Point) const
    {

    if(scnr.hasPoint())
        return scnr.getIndex();
    else
        return ~Result(0);
    }
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators

Comment: Thanks to operator overloading, that can do pretty much anything... Need more code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Simple::Result` has overloaded the bitwise not operator (`~`). This will call the overloaded operator in the `Simple::Result` class and return the result.

If the `~` operator performs a bitwise not operation, that function should return a `Simple::Result` that is all 1s (in binary) when `scnr.hasPoint` returns false.

You can read more about the bitwise not operator [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Comment: That's certainly one way it might work, but there's another: `Result` could have an overload ala `operator int()` that allows implicit conversion to a type (`int` is one of many) for which `~` is supported.